# Determine $a<0$ such that $\int_a^0 f(x) dx = f(a)$

Tags: calculus, integration

The function $f$ is given by
$$f(x)=\frac{e^{\frac 1 x}}{x^2}$$
where $x\ne 0$. Determine a number $a<0$ such that

$$\int_a^0 f(x) dx = f(a)$$

Comment: Did you try $u$-substitution?

Comment: First solve the integral (substitute $u=1/x$ and $du=-1/x^2*dx$) and then solve the equation for a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go ahead and compute the integral. You have
$$
\int_a^0 f(x) dx=\lim_{\epsilon \uparrow 0} \int_a^\epsilon \frac{e^{1/x}}{x^2}dx=\lim_{\epsilon\uparrow 0}(-e^{1/\epsilon}+e^{1/a})=e^{1/a}.
$$
Here, $\epsilon<0$ and I used $u=1/x$ substitution to integrate. You should be able to finish from here.